# gcloud compute instances describe self

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I am in google cloud, in google compute engine.

I am inside an instance in a managed instance group, What is the best command for giving me the output of...

```
gcloud compute instances describe my-instance-group-ab12 --zone=us-central1-b
```

... about the current machine, without having to provide the instance name? Something similar to this concept:

```
gcloud compute instances describe self
```

I just made that command up, just to communicate what I am after.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Generally you can use `/usr/share/google/get_metadata_value` to get most metadata and construct a command from there if more is required.

Example:

`/usr/share/google/get_metadata_value`

`/usr/share/google/get_metadata_value name`

`/usr/share/google/get_metadata_value disks/`

Comment: sounds like it should work, but I don't have those folders in my google compute engine instance, it was built with the google image of debian stretch (9), and for what I read int he documentation, that directory is the old way of doing things: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript

Comment: sounds like this is an alternative but this requires making http requests...  I would think the information lived on th server itself... https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata

Comment: The old script actually does http requests to the metadata server.  AFAIK no data lives in the instance itself.